# FQDN/URL format validator regex in Angular 2

Tags: regex, angular

I am new to regex. Could anyone point to or suggest a regex expression to validate a fully qualified domain name (like so - mysite.com) or a url validator regex without the protocol check?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This Should Work:

Regexp:

```
/^([a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9]{2,}$)/gm
```

Input:

```
mysite.com
test.net
testing.-com
camels.com.net
```

Output:

```
mysite.com
test.net
```

JavaScript Code:

```js
const regex = /^([a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9]{2,}$)/gm;
const str = `mysite.com
test.net
testing.-com
camels.com.net`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/ncVEAT/3